# Yet another "This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play" - But different this time

Tags: android, in-app-billing

Ok, I'm having the "This version of the application is not configured for billing through Google Play" on one of our apps. Sorry to ask this again, but I read more then 20 answers about this, and they always say the same things that I already checked:

- The apk installed is signed with the correct key
- The version code of the installed app is the same of the published version on Google Play
- There are no test users
- The license key is correctly set
- The app is published for weeks, so it's not a delay problem

Should I fill a bug report? Should I update the In-App API to Version 3?

---

Update: I unpublished the app, and published again, now it's working. Maybe it was some bug on new version of Play

Comment: Has the in-app billing ever worked with this app?  In other words, is this a new issue that just started happening with no change on your part, or has in-app billing always been broken?

Comment: Now that asked, I saw in the sale report that some people managed to buy it. But we couldn't in 2 different devices, and we got some angry calls from clients who couldn't buy it too...

Comment: It looks like you have solved your own problem.  Glad to hear that it is working now.  The recommended way to deal with a question on StackOverflow that you have solved yourself is to put your solution in an Answer, rather than adding it on to your Question.  You can even accept your own answer.  That way it is easy for others in the future to quickly see that there is a solution available.